# Implementing Page-Specific Styles in React Components using Higher-Order Components (HOC)

Tags: reactjs, components, solid-principles, clean-architecture

I'm working on a React project where I have a common component (let's say, a button) that needs to have different styles on different pages of my application. I've been exploring the idea of using Higher-Order Components (HOCs) for this purpose to maintain clean and modular code.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a BasicButton component, and I want to create LandingButton and RegisterButton components with page-specific styles using an HOC approach. Each button component should inherit the core functionality of BasicButton but also apply styles specific to its respective page (e.g., landing or registration).

Here's a basic structure of my components:

```
// BasicButton.js
// ... (core button component)

// LandingButton.js
// ... (HOC-wrapped button with landing page styles)

// RegisterButton.js
// ... (HOC-wrapped button with registration page styles)
```

My questions are:

1- Does using HOCs in this manner make sense for managing page-specific styles?

2- Are there any best practices or potential pitfalls I should be aware of when implementing page-specific styles using HOCs in React?

3- Are there alternative approaches that might offer better maintainability and performance in similar scenarios?

I'd appreciate any guidance, code examples, or insights on how to effectively implement this pattern in a clean and efficient way.

thanks for your help